# Is the block of "genesis_height" a special one in NEAR Protocol?

Tags: nearprotocol

There is a `genesis_height` field in the `genesis.json` config. Can we assume that querying some state (account balance, access keys) against that block will reveal the genesis state, i.e. no extra transactions can be in that block.

P.S. I need this to properly expose genesis data via Rosetta RPC exposing it via /block/ API, so it needs some block height and block hash (I may implement it as a fake block height -1 and block hash of all zeros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we assume that querying some state (account balance, access keys) against that block will reveal the genesis state, i.e. no extra transactions can be in that block.

Yes there can be no transaction in the genesis block.